# Как прижать перескакивающие блоки к низу на флексе?

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы блоки которые съехали прижались к низу, а верхние остались сверху?
Нужно что-то вроде `"align-items: space-between"`, но такого значения нет, есть идеи?

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 220px;
  width: 320px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `align-content: space-between;`. Он работает также на поперечной оси, как и `justify-content` на главной оси.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 220px;
  width: 320px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!